# Laravel 8 Controller does not exist, namespace is in routes and problem only exists on an apache webserver but works locally

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I'm currently trying to get a small laravel 8 project to work on an apache webserver. It works on localhost with artisan and in xampp, however doing exactly the same on the apache webserver I have access to doesn't work.

This is my Controller with namespace and its name:

[image: namespace with Controller name]

These are the functions I'm trying to use

```
   function showProfile()
    {
        return view("accountinfo");
    }
   function startup()
    {
        return view("landing");
    }
   function courseOverview()
    {
        return view("courses");
    }
```

This is the namespace in routes which should work as shown in other answers to similar posts as well as the routes I'm trying to use.

[image: Route namespace]

[image: routes]

This is the only controller that does not work on the server. I am using Laravel Breeze for basic authentication and those routes and controllers work fine. I tried adding and removing the namespace as well as the following commands that "worked" for other people:

```
php artisan clear-compiled 

php artisan optimize:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

Earlier I had permission issues that I managed to resolve for that particular error. Could this type of error arise from a similar issue? Permissions however are the same for all Auth controllers as well as my KnowledgeController. Let me know if you need more information or code from my end.

[Here you can find the stack trace](https://flareapp.io/share/yPaV8Ew7)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `use App\http\Controllers\KnowledgeController;` has `http` in all lower case though. So in case anything is case sensitive that might be an issue? (in routes)

Comment: Could you share the whole of the controller code? I think there's an issue when it tries to resolve the container, are you using dependency injection on the constructor?

Comment: jesus christ, that's it. I can't believe I missed that. Yea, namespaces are case sensitive. Thanks a lot, these have been a frustrating couple of hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespaces seem to be case sensitive for the webserver, and I didn't manage to catch the typo. Local artisan and xampp seem to be able to handle it even though it's not correct. The apache webserver had a problem with it. It's supposed to be

```
use App\Http\Controllers\KnowledgeController;
```

Comment: Now you learned what to look when get error message of non-existing class. ;)

Comment: Sounds like your local environment is Windows based and your apache webserver is *nix based. Windows filesystem is not case sensitive; *nix filesystems are. This is why Windows can find the file and *nix can't.